# libtool failed with exit code 1 on XCode 4.3

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.3

I have XCode 4.3 and I am getting this frustrating xml-lib related error. I have a feeling its because of the fact that 4.3 is not using /Developer folder but instead the /Applications/XCode.app/... The error message is below:

```
Libtool /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWEngines-ewchevfhokeivnffrputdqapsyxu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RWEngines.framework/Versions/A/RWEngines normal i386
cd /Users/dkatz/Sites/xCode/RWA/RWEngines
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool -static -arch_only i386 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk -L/Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWEngines-ewchevfhokeivnffrputdqapsyxu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWEngines-ewchevfhokeivnffrputdqapsyxu/Build/Intermediates/RWEngines.build/Release-iphonesimulator/RWEngines.build/Objects-normal/i386/RWEngines.LinkFileList -ObjC -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework UIKit /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWEngines-ewchevfhokeivnffrputdqapsyxu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libCorePlot-CocoaTouch.a -framework SenTestingKit -framework QuartzCore -framework Foundation -framework RWCommon -o /Users/dkatz/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RWEngines-ewchevfhokeivnffrputdqapsyxu/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/RWEngines.framework/Versions/A/RWEngines
```

And the actual error:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/libtool failed with exit code 1

Thanks guys!

Comment: I also installed XCode 4.3 from App Store rather than the dmg file. Could that be  the issue?

Comment: Is your target iOS Simulator?

Answer (score 2):

I was having this problem. I was following this tutorial for embedding webview in phonegap application- http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_cordova-webview_ios.md.html#Embedding%20Cordova%20WebView%20on%20iOS

i added'-Obj-C' in 'other linker flags' as said in point 12.
I just changed -Obj-C to -ObjC and it worked !!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will help you, but I got rid of that error by removing the "-licucore" linker flag that was set in the "Other Linker flags" build setting. This seems to be the regex library for Mac OSX.

Comment: Where do i find that? I did a search via "licucore" in build and target and couldnt find it. I nmy other linker flags I have "-all_load -ObjC"

Comment: In my project it was next to those flags. Sorry. Btw, turns out that it links the ICU lib for intl strings that is used by regex. I know, not pertinent.

Comment: Ok, so exit 1 is a generic error. If you want to see a more detailed error message, you can copy/paste the first few lines from your post into the terminal and get the raw error message from libtool.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when I was attempting to Archive for ad-hoc testing and discovered that it was complaining because I had a space character in my scheme name. To fix this I went to Manage Schemes and removed spaces from the name.

My specific error was

`clang: error: '-I-' not supported, please use -iquote instead`

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when switching from
Xcode 4.6 Developer Preview 1 to
Xcode 4.6 Developer Preview 2

and the fix is to re-add all the frameworks to your projects !

All frameworks (iAd, QuartzCore, GameKit,StoreKit,etc) were still pointing to the Xcode path from DP1. I just needed to rebind them to DP2. Additionally when adding frameworks select "Relative to SDK"rather than "Absolute Path" as some frameworks (10% of them) were still pointing to the right path.

Answer (score 0):

This might help.

In project build settings try removing the build settings for "Other Interface Builder Compiler Flags" (if -Wmost is set, set it to nil).

Project --> Build settings ---> Other Interface Builder Compiler Flags --> set to none(empty).